# MongoDB documentation confusing

Tags: mongodb

The MongoDB docs seem good overall, the only issue I have is that it uses the console syntax in the reference.

I do not understand why they chose to use that, because it's completely useless to every developer that needs to talk to the DB over the network. What I would need is how the commands are issued in their BSON/JSON form (e.g. `db.collection.ensureIndex`).

Are there any better references for that, except messing around with the driver source?

Comment: Are you planning on not using one of the officially support driver libraries, but instead reverse-engineering the network protocol?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the only logical choice. The common denominator, so to say. Everyone is expected to be familiar with javascript api (shell language).

Documentation on how to use certain drivers is also provided in the drivers' section. Here's one [for Ruby](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Ruby+Language+Center#RubyLanguageCenter-RubyDriver), for example.

I, personally, find it annoying when people post questions on mongodb and provide code in PHP (or Java, or another language that I am not too familiar with). In majority of cases, the question or problem is not driver related and can as easily be expressed with javascript api, which everybody can understand.

Comment: Amen kind sir! Generalize your questions so it reaches a wide audience. Too many SO questions are language or mapper specific.

Comment: Since BSON is mongos native data type, it would be also a common denominator. That hasn't anything to do with a language.